# ODI 12c Groovy - Automatically generate scenarios of a mapping with two physical layers

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I want to create a groovy script that will generate two scenarios of a mapping that have two physical layers.

I have the code below, but it seems that it's not correct. I try to pass as value for "generateSecnario" method, the physical layer. Don't know if it's ok.

```
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiProjectFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiDataStoreFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiFolderFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiDataStore;
import oracle.odi.domain.model.OdiModel;
import oracle.odi.domain.model.finder.IOdiModelFinder;
import oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;
import oracle.odi.generation.support.OdiScenarioGeneratorImpl;
import oracle.odi.generation.IOdiScenarioGenerator;
import oracle.odi.domain.runtime.scenario.OdiScenario;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.runtime.scenario.finder.IOdiScenarioFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProject;



txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)
def fm = ((IMappingFinder) tme.getFinder(Mapping.class)) // shorcut to Find Mapping
def mappingList = fm.findAll().findAll {w-> w.getProject().getCode() == 'DL_GENERATE_MAPPINGS'
}

if (mappingList == null) {
    println "Map is null"
}
ms = mappingList.iterator()
while (ms.hasNext()) {
    ms_i = ms.next()
    println ms_i.getName()
    scenName = ms_i.getName();

    stxnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
    stm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
    stme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
    stxnStatus = stm.getTransaction(stxnDef)

    OdiScenario sc = ((IOdiScenarioFinder) stme.getFinder(OdiScenario.class)).findLatestByName(scenName)
    if (sc != null) {
        println "Scenario already exist"
        println sc
    }
    println("test");
    odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().persist(ms_i);
    PhysicalDesignList = ms_i.getExistingPhysicalDesigns();
    println("ceva" + PhysicalDesignList);
    for (pd in PhysicalDesignList) {
        if (pd.getName() == "DailyLayer") {
            println("test1");
            IOdiScenarioGenerator gene = new OdiScenarioGeneratorImpl(odiInstance);
            OdiScenario newScen = gene.generateScenario(ms_i, scenName, "100");
        } else if (pd.getName() == "CorrectionLayer") {
            println("test2");
            IOdiScenarioGenerator gene = new OdiScenarioGeneratorImpl(odiInstance);
            OdiScenario newScen = gene.generateScenario(ms_i, scenName, "200");
        }
    }

    println newScen
    //tme.persist(newScen)
    stm.commit(stxnStatus)
    println "Created"
    //odiInstance.close()
}
tm.commit(txnStatus)
```

Do you know how to do this ?

Thank you,

**UPDATE 1**

If I change "ms_i" in generateScenario method with "pd" (generating scenario for each physical layer instead of each mapping), I god this error:

Hi, I forgot to mention that I already replaced with pd and tried. When I run this first, I got this error:

> No such property: newScen for class: Generate_scenarios_v1 (Subtract
>   18 from the error line number to account for the standard imports)
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: newScen for
>   class: Generate_scenarios_v1  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
>     at Generate_scenarios_v1.run(Generate_scenarios_v1.groovy:80)   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:497)     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:170)     at
>   oracle.di.studio.groovy.GroovyScriptRunInstance.run(GroovyScriptRunInstance.java:222)

After this, I i'll try to run it again, it goes into loop or something like that .. it doesn't do anything, like it's blocked by something. Maybe I need to close some connection and I don't do it ...

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the [generateScenario](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/index.html?oracle/odi/generation/IOdiScenarioGenerator.html) method you are invoking is of type [IOdiScenarioSource](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/project/IOdiScenarioSource.html). One of the implementation of this interface is [MapPhysicalDesign](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/physical/MapPhysicalDesign.html), so you could pass that instead of your mapping.

```
OdiScenario newScen = gene.generateScenario(pd, scenName, "100");
```

I see you are using the same name for the two scenarii with a different version number. This might lead to some confusion in the long run, especially because executing version -1 of a scenario will take the latest version (so the correction in your case). I would recommend to use 2 different names (e.g. `scenName+'_DAILY'` and `scenName+'_CORR'`)